# ¿Por qué recibo el error ":RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"? en django

Tags: python, django, poo, recursión

estoy explorando django, actualmente conozco angular, pero al querer llamar una vista con un modelo me tira el error de limite de recursión excedido, y la base de datos esta vacia, ya lei y busque y no veo nada malo que este haciendo.
este es el error

> RecursionError at /list/
> maximum recursion depth exceeded
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/
> Django Version: 4.1.5
> Exception Type: RecursionError
> Exception Value:
> maximum recursion depth exceeded
> Exception Location: G:\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\tree.py, line 40, in _new_instance
> Raised during:  main.views.list
> Python Executable:  G:\django\env\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.11.1
> Python Path:
> ['G:\django\env',
> 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip',
> 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib',
> 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311',
> 'G:\django\env',
> 'G:\django\env\Lib\site-packages']

No se que estoy haciendo mal realmente

este es el modelo en models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

esta es la view que llama al modelo en views.py de main

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import personal

# Create your views here.

def list(request):
    personals = list(personal.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(personals, safe=False)
```

y estan son las urls, de main

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.list),
    path('', views.main),
]
```

y la url principal que llama a esta

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls'))
]
```

gracias por la ayuda y atencion.

Comment: Hola @Jose Rodriguez, la recursión, si no está bien implementada, puede llevar a un bucle infinito, más allá de eso, se que python tiene un límite máximo  para la cantidad de recursiones... seguramente el problema pasas por ahí.

Comment: En tu método `°`list``` en ```personals=list(...)```  estas entrando en llamada recursiva a ese método y no tienes un punto de salida, por lo tanto, se hace infinito. Verifica si realmente es el método ```list``` que quieres invocar,, de lo contrario, tienes que poner un punto de salida. Creo que quieres asignar una lista pero justo tu método se llama ```list``` no utilices nombres de métodos iguales al de las librerías python.

Comment: En todo casa cámbiale el nombre ```list``` por ```listar```, por poner un ejemplo y modificas el urlpattern : ```path('list/', views.list),``` por ```path('list/', views.listar)```

Comment: Solo estoy adivinando y ya te lo dijo juan, pero lo aclaro por las dudas. Supongo que no era tu intención crear una función recursiva, si no convertir `personal.objects.values()` en una lista. Pero como reemplazaste el método list de Python en el entorno global de views.py por tu función list, Python llama a la función list que creaste. Luego en la segunda ejecución se choca con el mismo problema, creando una recursión infinita que es detenida por el limite de recursión.

Comment: Y que suerte que eso pasó, si no hubiera un limite de recursión, tu error sería "el programa se queda trabado sin hacer nada" y te hubieras dado más golpes en la cabeza tratando de resolverlo.

Comment: muchas gracias @JuanCarlosGuibovich no me habia fijado eso

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta para cerrar el apoyo. Un gusto haberte ayudado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu método `list`:

```
def list(request):
    personals = list(personal.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(personals, safe=False)
```

Invocas al metodo nuevamente y eso lo hace recursivo y no tienes un punto de salida, por lo tanto, se hace infinito.

Verifica si realmente es el método list que quieres invocar,, de lo contrario, tienes que poner un punto de salida. Creo que quieres asignar una lista pero justo tu método se llama list no utilices nombres de métodos iguales al de las librerías python.

Una solución es cambiar el nombre y adecuar el urlpattern:

```
def listar(request):
    personals = list(personal.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(personals, safe=False)

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.listar),
    path('', views.main),
]
```